# unable-to-record-speaker-output-using-audacity-in-Ubuntu 23-04

Tags: audacity

In Ubuntu 23.04 Audacity will not record at all and there none of the listed options shown work to record audio. ALSA is the only alternative and including my microphone listed in sound settings is not even shown in the audio input options.